# Select all text in files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there a way in eclipse to view the code from multiple files in a temp file. So if I highlight multiple .java files I can view the code from all files concatenated top-down as a single file instead of copying/pasting the files into one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find an eclipse way of doing it. But to use dos just cd into the package you want to merge the files and use - "copy *.java merge.java" This will merge all the files into one file called merge.java . Better than nothing.